# Painting around baby?

Tags: toddler, infant, health, safety

I was going to do some indoor painting today and I was wondering if it is ok for me to throw my 1 year old daughter into her backpack while I do it.  I would open all of the doors/windows in the room while I was painting.

Does this seem safe or would it be better to find somewhere else for her to hang out?

Comment: You're making my back hurt just talking about it :-)

Comment: The question epitomises the crazy things we come up with to try to look after a small child whilst getting on with life.

Comment: oooooh! I read "Painting around baby" as a literal term, haha.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The US EPA [recommends](http://www.epa.gov/opptintr/exposure/pubs/inpaint5.pdf) keeping young children from freshly painted rooms.

I would look into paints that off-gas fewer chemicals if I were to paint around a baby or young toddler.  You can find several.  Here is a list of [five](http://www.treehugger.com/green-home/5-zero-voc-interior-paints-renovation-healthy-home.html) and here is a Consumer Reports [comparison](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/magazine-archive/march-2009/home-garden/interior-paints/overview/interior-paints-ov.htm).

Purely anecdotally my mother threw me into a backpack to paint our home when I was a baby and I don't think it had any lasting negative impacts, but one instance does not make solid data.

Comment: Low-VOC paints are nice for the person painting, too! :-)

Comment: ..and the environment. You can get entirely water-based paints (as on some of my daughter's toys), but I doubt they'd be suitable for real decorating.